# In action script 3, how can I get collision to work with my two objects?

Tags: actionscript-3

I am creating a simple slider shooting game where there are randomly spawned enemies and a single playable character. If one of these two objects collide with each other then I want them to be destroyed. Then my final frame of game over screen appears with the final score. I know this involves the command `hitTestPoint` but I don't know how to implement it. Both my objects are movie clips which are in separate classes. The playable character is called `PlayerFront` and its instance is called `PlayerFrontOne` while the enemy object is called `EnemyScout` but has no instance of it on the stage because it's generated randomly during gameplay. The code which I have so far is:

```
public function PlayerFront()
{
  stage.addEventListener (Event.ENTER_FRAME, collision);
}

function collision(evt:Event)
{
    if (PlayerFront.hitTestPoint(EnemyScout, true))
    {
        score = score + 1;
        trace(score);
    }
}
```

I keep getting errors but can't work out why.

Comment: `hitTestPoint`, as its name indicates takes a point as an argument. What you are looking for is probably `hitTestObject`

Comment: how would I do that?

Comment: What kind of errors do you receive?

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
 var enemy : EnemyScout =  new EnemyScout();

 public function PlayerFront() {
      stage.addEventListener (Event.ENTER_FRAME, collision);
    }

    function collision(evt:Event) {
        if (PlayerFront.hitTestObject(enemy)) { //here you need to test with EnemyScout instance
            score = score + 1;
            trace(score);
        }
    }
```

If you have many EnemyScout instances then you need to loop throw all of them and check the collision with each object.

something like this:

you can create an array with enemys

```
 var enemy_arr : Array = [];
```

everytime you create an enemey, you will push it to your array

```
 var enemy : EnemyScout =  new EnemyScout();
 enemy_arr.push(enemy);
```

now you can loop throw your enemy array like this:

```
    ...
        function collision(evt:Event) {
            if (areHittingEnemy()) { //here you need to test with EnemyScout instance
                score = score + 1;
                trace(score);
            }
        }

       function areHittingEnemy() : Boolean {
           for each(var e in enemy_arr){
               if(PlayerFront.hitTestObject(e)){
                  //if you want you cand remove this enemy from array
                  return true;
               }
           } 
           return false;
       }
```

Hope this helps. All the best!

Comment: Im getting an error on hitTestObject saying "call to a possibly undefined method hitTestObject through a reference with a static class type"

Comment: did your class extends MovieClip? you have to extends some DisplayObject, because here you have the method hitTestObject... So, try to extend MovieClip...